# Design Decision: Adding new field to Core Data model and sorting with it

Tags: objective-c, sorting, core-data

I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to display a table of my `NSManagedObject` data.

Up to now, I've been using the `name` property on my objects to sort them:

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:[Item entityName]];
NSSortDescriptor* nameSorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
request.sortDescriptors = @[nameSorter];
self.frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                   managedObjectContext:self.moc
                                                     sectionNameKeyPath:@"nameInitial"
                                                              cacheName:nil];
```

Note that my `sectionNameKeyPath` is different from my sort request. As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1741131/1827743), I use a transient property on `Item`, called `nameInitial`. Its getter just reads name and returns the first letter.

So far so good. But now, I want to add a special condition: if the first word of the name is 'the', I don't want to sort by that. I want to sort by the first letter of the 2nd word. I can't do this with a transient property because now, the `NSSortDescriptor` on the fetch request will give a different order than the `sectionNameKeyPath`, which makes `NSFetchedResultsController` barf.

So I added a `nameInitial` field to `Item` and performed a lightweight migration. Now, I can add a `NSSortDescriptor` using this new attribute. I just have to populate it with the right letter. This is where my problem comes in: What do I do with the objects I already have in the DB, for which the `nameInitial` attribute is nil? As far as I can tell, these are my options:

- Write a code that executes upon the first launch of the new version of the app, reads all the `name` fields and updates `nameInitial` appropriately.
- Use `awakeFromFetch` to automatically update `nameInitial` for each object as it is loaded.
- Override the getter of `nameInitial`, so it updates itself if it's nil.

I don't particularly like any of these options. The first one isn't elegant at all, and the last two mean either the `awakeFromFetch` or the getter will have unexpected side-effects. Is there a better way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do any of those. You should be writing a migration which processes this instead of using a lightweight (auto) migration (which can only fill the values in as `nil`).

Technically, your suggestions will work, but they aren't 'correct', will run slower and will be a maintenance burden in the future.

---

From your comment, the best option then is your first suggestion. You don't have many choices - use the built in migration processing or write your own version check and migration logic.

Comment: The problem is I believe Marcus Zarra vehemently advices against using heavy migration to the point where he essentially says "do whatever it takes to avoid it" (paraphrasing). I don't remember why - I've given the book away atm.

Comment: I haven't read that, do you have an online reference? Marcus certainly knows what he's talking about though

Comment: I don't have the book at the moment, but I think the book followed the gist of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15800585/1827743). The main objection seems to be its poor performance. However, my data model is very simple. I might actually experiment with it and if it's not unbearable, I'll go with heavy migration.